# Cross-plattform virtual webcam

Tags: camera, virtual, webcam

I am looking for a cross-platform way to create a virtual webcam (and microphone) with a static image (and fixed sound - i.e. no sound).

[Manycam](https://manycam.com/) does something similar, but i want it to be running invisibly in the background or even in-process (in java).

Any ideas which software or project can do this?